# Php Mysql - Not throw an error when I know there an undefined variable

Tags: php, model-view-controller

So I have a child parent relationship table.  Asset_id, parent_id.

Web url will look like... example.com/assets/edit/x/y/z

For example,  Below is not code, just an explanation.

```
Level 1 (first variable = $x) is a book.
example.com/assets/edit/1 (this should be viewable without error)
example.com/assets/edit/x
This shows the book (asset_id = $x) and maybe a description (of $x) of the book on the EDIT page.

Level 2 (2nd variable = $y) is a chapter.
example.com/assets/edit/1/34 (this should be viewable without error)
example.com/assets/edit/x/y
This shows the chapter ($y = 34) that belongs to book ($x = 1)  and maybe a description of the chapter on the EDIT page. $y has parent_id = $x.

Level 3 (3rd variable) is a scene.
example.com/assets/edit/1/34/58
example.com/assets/edit/x/y/z
This shows the scene ($z) that belongs to chapter ($y) and maybe a description of the chapter on the EDIT page. $z has parent_id = $y.
```

I am using MVC structure.  I have successfully displayed all three variables. So in reality everything is fine when I am looking at a "scene".  I can, however, view a chapter like this...

example.com/assets/edit/1  or a chapter like ...

example.com/assets/edit/1/34  But when I do I am getting an error that says (Missing argument 2 or missing argument 2 and 3) AND (undefined variable z, or undefined variable z and y)

I think I understand these errors and I see why they are thrown.  But how do I create it so i don't get those errors?  Here is some code from my MVC structure.
Controller:

```
    public function edit($x , $y, $z){
    $this->View->render(`assets/editbook`, array(
    `chapters` =>AssetsModel::getChapters($x),
    'scenes' =>AssetsModel::getScenes($y),
    'chapterid' => AssetsModel::getChapterID($y),
    'sceneid' => AssetsModel::getSceneID($z))); }
```

I'm not sure the Model or View code has any relevance here.  If it is needed let me know.

Comment: I think when you are viewing a chapter or the book, you should assign null to the other parameters so that it will not through any error.

Comment: `public function edit($x , $y = null, $z = null){`

Comment: That's it!  Such a long explanation for a simple answer.  I did have to do some if/elseif/else on my page.  but at least the errors are gone now.  Thanks so much!